# Complex series MC

Tags: real-analysis

I'm currently stuck on a problem and don't understand why a&b and c&d are different from eachother. Could someone please explain them to me and also why only a and d are correct statements?

Let $(z_n)$ be a sequence in $\mathbb{C}$, $z \in \mathbb{C}$, and $z_n = r_ne^{i\theta_n}$, with $r_n, r > 0$, and $\theta_n, \theta \in [0, 2\pi)$. Which of the following statements are always true?

a. The sequence $z_n$ converges to $z$ as $n \to \infty$ if and only if $\text{Re}(z_n) \to \text{Re}(z)$ and $\text{Im}(z_n) \to \text{Im}(z)$ as $n \to \infty$.

b. The sequence $z_n$ converges to $z$ as $n \to \infty$ if and only if $r_n \to r$ and $\theta_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

c. If $|z_n| - |z| \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$, then $z_n \to z$ as $n \to \infty$.

d. If $z_n - z \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$, then $|z_n| - |z| \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*a. Correct.* Use triangle inequality. If $z = x + \textbf{i}y$:

$$ \max(x, y) \le |z| \le  |x| + |y|$$

*b. Incorrect.* Example:

$$z_n = 1 + \textbf{i}\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$$

It is easy to see that $z_n\to 1$, but $\theta_n$ can be splitted into two subsequences (with odd and even indices) with different limits ($0$ and $2\pi$). The main idea
here to understand is that complex number argument function is not continuous.

*c. Incorrect.* Example:

$$z_n = \exp\left\{\textbf{i}\frac{1}{n}\right\}$$

For any natural number $n$: $|z_n|=1$, so sequence $\{|z_n|\}$ is constant and converges to 1, but $\{z_n\}$ infinitely travels around a unit circle.

*d. Correct.* We can again use the inequality from *a* and the fact that $f(x,y)=\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ is continuous function.

$$z_n\to z \Leftrightarrow x_n\to x, y_n\to y \Rightarrow 
|z_n|=\sqrt{x_n^2+y_n^2}\to \sqrt{x^2+y^2} = |z|
$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. This question goes against our [quality standard policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508). Instead of posting an answer, you should encourage the person who posted the question to improve it.

Comment: Counter example in c is not correct. It can be changed to $\exp\{\textbf i\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{1}{j}\}$